# Can Windows 10 act as UPnP server?

Tags: windows-10, upnp

One of the primary purpose of my Windows 7 Pro 64bit is to use it as UPnP server to stream my movies to  my Panasonic Viera VT50.

It's the one thing I couldn't yet figure out before upgrading: will I out of the box be able to do it?

I read that certain Multimedia components are going to be removed but it's unclear to me whether I'm affected or not.

thanks

Comment: what software are you using to stream over UPNP discoverable protocols?

Comment: I'm just using the natively available media streaming options, I don't use any third party software (to my knowledge).

Comment: so you are using Windows Media Player?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I've set up that files belonging to my media library are in a certain directory and this one gets auto-discovered by my TV. I play via TV.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 operates just like Windows 7 and Windows 8.  You need to switch on Media Sharing  in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Media streaming options.  It's a bit snappier than Windows 8 too :-)

Answer (score 1):

See: [Universal Media Server](http://www.universalmediaserver.com/)

That program you run on your PC and it takes care of everything.  Everything.  It is the most compatible program for creating a UPnP Media Server and supports a whole lot of client devices and will even transcode your source media to a better format for a client if needed.

It is pretty well automatic, and after many frustrating hours trying to solve your exact problem this is what I settled on.

Comment: And it's Open Source and Free.

Answer (score -1):

Not out of the box. You will still need third party software like plex or tversity to use your computer as a media server to stream to other devices.

Comment: Plex isn't free and TVersity sucks, I tried both.  TVersity was free when I initially tried it but they moved to payment some time after that.  TVersity also uses DirectShow Filters and the coverage for all kinds of media isn't great and the transcoding performance leaves much to be desired.  UMS as I answered uses FFMPEG for transcoding and that program just performs so much better that TVersity's filters.